# Setup project for small wpf app and localdb

Tags: wpf, installation, localdb

I built a small project that uses LocalDB, now it's time to move it to the customer, I want to understand how to build the Setup File?
I tried with the InstallShield software as normal but without success. Is there a difference? 
Also how to put the DB (it is not localized in this project just in V11)
Hope I could explain the problem, and thanks in advance for any reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use LocalDB on your client machines, you will need to do two things:

1. Install LocalDB on the client machine. It's a small installer and can be run silently with the following command:
   `msiexec /i SqlLocalDB.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES`.
   You should include this installer into the installer of your application. You can find more info on that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/11/28/simple-installer-for-localdb-has-shipped.aspx)
2. Locate the *.mdf and *.ldf files that you created (by default found in `%userprofile%`, check [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx) for more info) and make them available on the client machine. Put them in a directory your process can access and use that path in the connection string of your application. For example: `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Data\MyData.mdf;`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but where is the DB *.Mdf After I created the DB?

Comment: @Roel Problem, I couldn't get my connectionstring to work, I based it of yours. The problem is, for localdb use Data Source, not server: `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;`

Comment: the links are broken, can we have an explanation about this?